# how to put 2 elements from jq variables in one request?

Tags: bash, jq

There is a part of the script where each request receives a response and is written to a variable. How to do it in one request with writing to variables?

```
boolStatus=$(curl -X 'GET' \
  "https://tsit-app1/api/v2/workItems/$case?versionNumber=0" \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: $apiKey" | jq '.isAutomated')
echo $boolStatus

name=$(curl -X 'GET' \
  "https://tsit-app1/api/v2/workItems/$case?versionNumber=0" \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: $apiKey" | jq '.name')
  echo $name

I tried
curl -X 'GET' \
  "https://tsit-app1/api/v2/workItems/$case?versionNumber=0" \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H "Authorization: $apiKey" | jq '"boolStatus=\(.isAutomated)", "name=\(.name)"'
```

but in echo i get

```
"boolStatus=true", 
"name=bla bla"
```

need to

```
echo $boolStatus 
true
echo $name 
bla bla
```

Comment: Your attempt is basically fine, you just need to transform the output into something the shell can consume. If you are confident you can trust the sender, transform it to something the shell can `eval`. Otherwise, perhaps split across lines and pipe to `while IFS="" read -r`

Comment: Notice also that `jq -r` lets you get rid of the quotes and other JSON decorations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the [`@sh` string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Formatstringsandescaping) and then use your shell's `eval`.

Using the string interpolation would output something like:

```
boolStatus=true
name='abc'
```

which can then be fed to `eval`:

```
vars="$(curl ... | jq -r '@sh "boolStatus=\(.isAutomated)", @sh "name=\(.name)"')"
eval "$vars"
```

or explicitly output the line break:

```
jq -r '@sh "boolStatus=\(.isAutomated)\nname=\(.name)"'
```

Disclaimer: Note that this will evaluate *any* shell code and might open your system to malicious code (`@sh` escapes the values, but it's always a good idea to be aware of this).

Answer (score 1):

Use process substitution to allow two uses of `read` to read from the output of `jq`.

```
{ read boolStatus; read name; } < <(curl ... | jq -r '.isAutomated, .name')
```

(assuming the name does not contain any newlines).

At the very least, you can save the output to process with `jq` twice.

```
response=$(curl ...)
name=$(echo "$response" | jq -r .name)
boolStatus=$(echo "$response" | jq -r .isAutomated)
```